# my checkbox pass true and false, but i need 0 or 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i training on react and i have stated my checkbox as true or false, but my api needs to recibe 1 or 0, how can i do the change?

this is my checkboc code

```
const [vGender, setvGender] = useState(true);
 <View style={styles.checkbox} >
            <CheckBox
              containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
              textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
              uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
              checkedColor={"#911830"}
              title="Male"
              checkedIcon="stop"
              checked={vGender}
              onPress={()=>setvGender(true)}
              //onPress={() => this.setState({ checked1: !this.state.checked1, checked2: this.state.checked1 })}
            />
            <CheckBox
              containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
              textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
              uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
              checkedColor={"#911830"}
              title="Female"
              checkedIcon="stop"
              checked={!vGender}
              onPress={()=>setvGender(false)}
              //onPress={() => this.setState({ checked1: !this.state.checked1, checked2: this.state.checked1 })}
            />
          </View>
```

Comment: You can try `vGender ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 1 and 0 as state and maintain Checkbox states accordingly

```
const [vGender, setvGender] = useState(1);
 <View style={styles.checkbox} >
            <CheckBox
              containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
              textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
              uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
              checkedColor={"#911830"}
              title="Male"
              checkedIcon="stop"
              checked={vGender===1 ? true : false}
              onPress={()=>setvGender(1)}
              //onPress={() => this.setState({ checked1: !this.state.checked1, checked2: this.state.checked1 })}
            />
            <CheckBox
              containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
              textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
              uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
              checkedColor={"#911830"}
              title="Female"
              checkedIcon="stop"
              checked={vGender===0 ? true : false}
              onPress={()=>setvGender(0)}
              //onPress={() => this.setState({ checked1: !this.state.checked1, checked2: this.state.checked1 })}
            />
          </View>
```

Comment: tried this but it mark both checkboxes at the same time and it doesnt work as i cant mark or dismark one of them

Comment: Try the updated answer , I wrote the second condition wrong. I have fixed it now